# How to select a child in jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is the sample structure!

```
<div id ="div1">
    <div class="div1-child">
        <div class="div1-sub-child">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Can anyone help me how to apply jquery effects on the div1-sub-child when i hover the div1?

Answer (score 1):

You do not jquery to do this. Using just css you get it working. As below -

```
#div1:hover .div1-sub-child {
   background-color:yellow
}
```

Using jQuery -

```
$('#div1').hover({function(){  //this is called whn mouse enters the div
    $(this).find('.div1-sub-child').css('background-color','red'); //your effect here
},function(){   //this is called whn mouse leaves the div
    $(this).find('.div1-sub-child').css('background-color','green'); //your effect here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#div1").hover(
function()
{
    $(this).find('div.div1-sub-child').filter(':not(:animated)').animate(
    {
        marginLeft:'9px'
    },'slow');
},
function()
{
    $(this).find('div.div1-sub-child').animate(
    {
        marginLeft:'0px'
    },'slow');
});
```

Hover has two `callbacks` one will fire when you `hover` and second fire when `hoverOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
$(".div1-child").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.div1-sub-child').css(*** your new css ***);
  });
```

Comment: your function will select all elements with the class `div-sub-child` rgardless of their location in the DOM. use `$(this).find(selector)` to make it relativ to `this`

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
 $('#div1').hover({function(){  //this is called whn mouse enters the div
        $(this).find('.div1-sub-child').css('background-color','red'); //your effect here
    },function(){   //this is called whn mouse leaves the div
        $(this).find('.div1-sub-child').css('background-color','green'); //your effect here
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a special style to div, try:

```
$("#div1").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('div.div1-sub-child').addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find('div.div1-sub-child').removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very often when you are working with jquery and php .And there are lot's of way to do that here i am going to add one of them.Hope this may help you .

$('#div1 .div1-child').children().addClass('addclass');